# post on radio button click in mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web page with a table and two columns. One column has a radio button list. the second column has a check box list. My requirement is on selection of the radio button the checkbox list must be loaded. (eg: Departments as the radio button and on selection of the particular Department it shows me a list of Employees on the second column on the same page). I need to implement this using Ajax. The page has a Submit button, when the Submit button is clicked it captures the values of the radiobutton and the checkboxes on post back. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I am doing this on the radio button in the View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.radio').on("click", (function () {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');

    }));

});

</script>

---
---
--
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Company", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =              
"Employees", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id =      
"EmployeeForm" }))
{
----
---
@foreach (var depin Model.Departments)
                {
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, emp.DepartmentCode, new { @class =  
"radio", });

----
<td id="Employees">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_EmployeeList", Model);}
            </td>
<input class="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="ButtonName" />
}
```

_EmployeeList Partial View code:

```
 @foreach (var employee in Model.Employees.Where(i => i.DepartmentCode ==         
 Model.SelectedDepartment))
{

    if (Model.SelectedEmployees.Contains(employee .EmployeeCode))
    {
    <input type="checkbox" name="Select"  checked="checked"    
    value="@employee.EmployeeCode"></input> @employee.EmployeeName;
    }
    else
    {
    <input type="checkbox" name="Select"   value="@employee.EmployeeCode"></input> 
     @employee.EmployeeName;
    }                                                                                            


}
```

My Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(Company company, string ButtonName, String[] Select)
{
if (ButtonName != null)
    ----
    ----
    return JavaScript(string.Format("document.location='{0}';", "/Home"));
else
    return PartialView("_EmployeeList", company);
}
```

The [] Select stores the Employees selected in a comma separated string. Hope this helps. What is happening right now is when I change the radio button it shows a new page with the Employee List checkboxes. _EmployeeList is a partial view which contains the checkbox list.

Comment: Share whatever code you've put together.

Comment: Please post what you have tried